# Fetch data before resolve route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, routes, react-router

I´m using for routing "react-router" lib. Before render page component, I need fetch data. I want show loader before every routing, because all routes need data from server. All my components is driven by controller, so my solution for this is create this controller in constructor of all components, and on create controller fetch data.

It works, but I´m using typescript and I want access to data without (!) check for data. Better solution for that use wrapper component which wait for data and render currently page. For first routing it works, but componentDidMounnt "below in code" is called only once, so second rounting doesnt work.

```js
<Router>
   <Switch>
     <MyRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
     <MyRoute path="/reg" component={RegistrationPage} exact={true} />
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

```js
/*MyRoute*/
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
            await this.props.routeController.getController(this.props.path).then((controller: PageController) => {
                this.setState({
                    controller: controller
                })
                this.props.routeController.loading = false;
            })
        } catch(err) {
            // error handling
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.props.routeController.loading) {
            const { controller } = this.state; 
            return (
                <this.props.component controller={controller} />
            )
        }

        return <div>LOADING</div>;
    }
```

So I need fetch data before routing. After that I need render page component with data in props. Is it possible or Is it good solution for this problem? If not, how can I solve problem with asynchronous routing. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make state isLoading : false,
Then in componentWiilMount() / DidMount() set isLoading state true.
After on fetch sucess reset isLoading to false;

```
componenetWillMount/didMount(){
this.setState({
isLoading: true
})
fetchData().then(res => this.setState(isLoading: false))
.catch(err => this.setState({isLoading: false}));


render(){
return(
{this.state.isLoading ? <Loader /> : <Component View /> }
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could use [react-router-loading](https://github.com/victortrusov/react-router-loading) to fetch data before switching the page.

You only need to mark routes with the `loading` prop and tell the router when to switch the pages using the context in components:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-loading";

<Routes> // or <Switch> for React Router 5
    <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} loading />
    <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} loading />
    ...
</Routes>
```

```
// Page1.jsx

import { useLoadingContext } from "react-router-loading";
const loadingContext = useLoadingContext();

const loading = async () => {
    // loading some data

    // call method to indicate that loading is done and we are ready to switch
    loadingContext.done();
};
```